# What's the difference between Live Edit and Source Edit in Firebug's CSS panel?

Tags: firebug, edit

I just did a Google search and can't find a straight forward answer to this. Question is what's the difference between the *Live Edit* and *Source Edit* options inside the toolbar of Firebug's *CSS* panel?

Answer (score 4):

*Source Edit* lets you edit the CSS as it was loaded by the browser. I.e. including comments and formatting.

*Live Edit* displays the CSS after it was interpreted by the browser. I.e. there are no comments and the CSS rules have a unified formatting.

See the [description of the CSS panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/CSS_Panel#Edit_Button) for more info.